# Unity - Writing texture data to byte array yields empty array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, unity-game-engine

I'm having a problem at the point of creating a byte array from texture data. I have two functions, one that writes texture to a file (which is working) and one that writes texture data to an array that then gets processed into a string. I'm trying to test to see if it works with a debug 'Debug.Log("Local variable textureString is : " + textureString);' but it's empty. What do I have wrong? Just to give a clear sense of what I'm trying to accomplish in whole I've created a diagram to illustrate:

[image]

So I have 4 clients running an application that allows users to create a custom texture and then a 5th client running a different application that takes that texture info and uses it to instantiate a custom character based on the texture2d, string animal type, and string client id.

```
    public byte[] textureBytes;
    public string textureString;
    public string textureType;

    public void WriteTextureToBytes()
    {
        SaveColoringBookTexturePNG();

        StartCoroutine(DoWriteTextureToBytes());
        Debug.Log("WriteTextureToBytes Button Pressed.");
    }

    IEnumerator DoWriteTextureToBytes()
    {
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        RenderTexture tmp = RenderTexture.active;
        RenderTexture.active = BackLayerController.RenderTexture;

        TmpTexture2D.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, RenderTextureSize.x, RenderTextureSize.y), 0, 0, false);

        textureBytes = TmpTexture2D.GetRawTextureData();
        textureString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(textureBytes);
        textureType = PageConfig.UniqueId;

        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
        player.GetComponent<PlayerController>().AnimalTex = textureString;
        player.GetComponent<PlayerController>().AnimalType = textureType;

        Debug.Log("Local variable textureType is : " + textureType);
        Debug.Log("Local variable textureString is : " + textureString);
        Debug.Log("PlayerController AnimalType is : " + player.GetComponent<PlayerController>().AnimalType);
        Debug.Log("PlayerController AnimalTex is : " + player.GetComponent<PlayerController>().AnimalTex);
    }

    public void SaveColoringBookTexturePNG()
    {
        StartCoroutine(DoSaveColoringBookTexturePNG());
    }

    IEnumerator DoSaveColoringBookTexturePNG()
    {
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        RenderTexture tmp = RenderTexture.active;
        RenderTexture.active = BackLayerController.RenderTexture;

        TmpTexture2D.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, RenderTextureSize.x, RenderTextureSize.y), 0, 0, false);

        File.WriteAllBytes(SaveFilePath, TmpTexture2D.EncodeToPNG());

        Debug.Log("File Saved to: " + SaveFilePath);
    }
```

Comment: Why are you converting texture byte array to string?

Comment: Ultimately, and this was something that you responded to earlier when i asked a question about sending data using unity networktransport is after reading through the information you posted i realized that i should first try to achieve what i need using the high level api as the low level is definitely way out of the range of my basic abilities currently. i thought that i needed to convert the array into a string before sending over the network. maybe i don't? how can i check the array to verify that it isn't empty? i have so much learn and i really appreciate all of your help.

Comment: No problem. You can check that the array is not empty by checking its size. `Array.length` or `textureBytes.length` in your particular case. It must be > 0 or else it is empty.  Please read the answer I left. Also read the comments in the code. They are very helpful to understand what's happening. I used the high level API this time which simplify everything. It uses `NetworkServer` and `NetworkClient`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought that I needed to convert the array into a string before
>   sending over the network. maybe I don't?

No. You can send byte array to players with [`NetworkServer.SendBytesToPlayer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkServer.SendBytesToPlayer.html) but I recommend you use `NetworkServer.SendToAll` since you want to send multiple data over the network. *Never convert Texture to string*. That is slow and bad programming.

Simply create a class that will hold all the variables you want to send over the network. Make sure that this class derives from [`MessageBase`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.MessageBase.html). When you derive from [`MessageBase`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.MessageBase.html), Unity will automatically serialize those variables inside that class for you so that you don't have to do that yourself.

**SERVER**:

Here is server example that holds a Texture array (`textureBytes`) and a simple string message:

```
public class MyMsgType
{
    public static short texture = MsgType.Highest + 1;
};

//Create a class that holds a variables to send
public class TextureMessage : MessageBase
{
    public byte[] textureBytes;
    public string message;//Optional
}

//Call to send the Texture and a simple string message
public void sendTexture(Texture2D texture, string message)
{
    TextureMessage msg = new TextureMessage();
    //Convert Texture2D to byte array
    msg.textureBytes = texture.GetRawTextureData();
    msg.message = message;

    NetworkServer.SendToAll(MyMsgType.texture, msg);
}
```

*USAGE*:

Then to simply send when connected to a network:

```
Texture2D textureToSend = ....;
string messageToSend = "Screen Short Image";

sendTexture(textureToSend , messageToSend);
```

---

**CLIENT**:

The client is easy too. Register `MyMsgType` event to be notified when you receive a `Texture2D`. When you receive it, use `LoadRawTextureData` to convert the byte array back to `Texture2D`.

```
public class MyMsgType
{
    public static short texture = MsgType.Highest + 1;
};

//Create a class that holds a variables to send
public class TextureMessage : MessageBase
{
    public byte[] textureBytes;
    public string message;//Optional
}

NetworkClient myClient;

// Create a client and connect to the server port
public void setupClient()
{
    //Create new client
    myClient = new NetworkClient();
    //Register to connect event
    myClient.RegisterHandler(MsgType.Connect, OnConnected);
    //Register to texture receive event
    myClient.RegisterHandler(MyMsgType.texture, OnTextureReceive);

    //Connect to server
    myClient.Connect("127.0.0.1", 4444);
}

//Called when texture is received
public void OnTextureReceive(NetworkMessage netMsg)
{
    TextureMessage msg = netMsg.ReadMessage<TextureMessage>();

    //Your Received message
    string message = msg.message;
    Debug.Log("Texture Messsage " + message);

    //Your Received Texture2D
    Texture2D receivedtexture = new Texture2D(4, 4);
    receivedtexture.LoadRawTextureData(msg.textureBytes);
    receivedtexture.Apply();
}

public void OnConnected(NetworkMessage netMsg)
{
    Debug.Log("Connected to server");
}
```

*USAGE*:

Register to receive event then connect to the server. Just call the `setupClient()` function to do both.

```
setupClient();
```

Comment: Thank you for all of your help @Programmer. I just attached a diagram of how the entire system should work above. Would you have a glance at it to confirm that I've got things right in mind and that things will work based on you input? Many, many thanks!

Comment: That looks ok  to me. I suggest you start small first. Don't try to do everything otherwise they might not even work. Send a simple image and see what happens. After that you can add more features to it. The code in my answer should get you started.

Comment: I've been trying to get my head around this but I can't grasp how to integrate everything correctly. I just went through tutorials on Commands and Client Rpcs and I don't see how it connects. Are there any simple working examples that you might be able to point me to that executes the process of taking a string on a client, passing it to the server and then having the server pass it to one specific client? I'm sorry, I really need help and I'm trying my best to understand but it's just not clicking yet. If I could see how all of the pieces go together I would get it.

Comment: So far, I added a sample script server and client script which you ignored for over a week. Create a server script and put the code in my answer to it. Create a client script and put the code in my answer to it. Now, try to get what's in my answer to work. If it does not work, create a new question with that server and client script and tell us what exactly *"doesn't work"*. That's the proper way to do this.

Comment: I'm sorry @Programmer. I actually haven't ignored it. I've been working on it and watching dozens and dozens of tutorials to figure out how it goes together. Where do I attach the client script in Unity? To a player object? I guess I'm just confused about where the scripts go. I'm so sorry, networking has me completely confused at the moment. I will continue to plug away until it makes sense. Thank you for all of your help and I'm sorry for any frustration that I've caused you.

Comment: That's what the comment section is for which means that if you were actually doing it, you would ask questions about it if you were stuck instead of replying 6 days later with how to use "RPC" to do this which has nothing to do with my answer. You simply attach those to two empty GameObjects. Ones named server and the other one named client. If you run into problems, you can create new question and supply the two scripts and tell what's not working.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm asking the wrong questions, I'm just learning about the networking side of things and I'm pretty twisted around on it as you can obviously tell. No disrespect to you, I'm trying to work through things. Sorry for being a dummy, I'm just really struggling to wrap my head around the entirety of the networking api and how it all interrelates.